# Calculating a gradient fill's start and end colours given a base colour

Tags: c++, winapi, colors, wtl

I have a WTL C++ application and I want the user to be able to select different colours for some of the UI elements and apply a gradient fill using the `GradientFill` API call.  However, instead of letting the user pick the start and end colours for the gradient, I'd like them to be able to select a 'base' colour and for my application to calculate suitable start/end colours automatically.  I want to end up with a fill that is similar to the one Windows uses for various themed elements.  The base colour could be the 'middle' colour of the gradient with my application somehow computing a slightly lighter colour for the gradient start and a slightly darker colour for the gradient end.  Alternatively I could use the base as the start colour and compute the end or vice-versa.

I'm sure this would be relatively easy with some RGB macro magic but I really don't know where to start.  Any ideas would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RGB color space is not suitable for this. Use [HSL or HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV): it is easy to auto-generate a good looking gradient by varying an individual component.  Converting from HSL/V to an RGB triplet you can use in the API is [simple](https://web.archive.org/web/20141023005253/http://bobpowell.net/RGBHSB.aspx).